# Storyboards - applications are expected to have a root view controller

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I just recently started using storyboards. I created an empty project for me to try to set up a split view controller. I don't want to use the master-detail template yet because there's already code generated there and it makes it difficult for me to understand how to create my own split view master-detail controller setup.

I dragged one Split view controller and two table view controllers to the storyboard. I also created 2 classes for the 2 table view controllers

I've already set the classes for the two table view controllers in the identity inspector. But when I run the application, I get a white screen and message on the console "applications are expected to have a root view controller"

This is the code in my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I also have another project which only has a 'return YES;' in its didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but I do not get "applications are expected to have a root view controller" in the console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your window does not have its `rootViewController` property set, in this case. The reason it worked the other way (`return YES` as you've described) is via a little Xcode magic with Storyboards. Did you try Googling the error message 'applications are expected to have a root view controller"?

Comment: Yes I did. The majority of the solution I saw was to create an instance of their view controllers and set that as the root view controller. But I'm confused because I did not do any of that in my previous project, and it worked.

Comment: It worked because Xcode had it all set up for you. You have to now create and add a ViewController manually. That's what you wanted to learn, right?